# What is the equivalent to RxJava PublishSubject in project-reactor?

Tags: project-reactor

What is the equivalent to RxJava PublishSubject in project-reactor? I need Flux on which I can call `next()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called `Sinks`. See Reactor reference: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#processors